# Capturing the OnExit event in WPF with MVVMCross

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling, mvvmcross

I need to explicitly close and dispose of a `SerialPort` object when my MVVMCross WPF application exits, i.e. when the red X is clicked.  In order to do this, I need to call a method of the current ViewModel.

I have been trying to do this by following the MVVMCross [n=42 video](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/n42-is-my-viewmodel-visible-can-i-kill.html) and adding an `IKillable` interface with a `public abstract void KillMe()` method in an `abstract BaseViewModel` class that implements `IKillable`.  Then, in the WPF project I added a `BaseView` class, exactly as he does in the video.  I am able to access methods of the current view model at this point.

In the video, the examples are IOS, Droid, and Windows Phone, where one can `override` events such as `OnNavigatedTo`, etc. In WPF, there is no `OnExit()` which I could `override` available in the `BaseView` class.

I am wondering, is there any way that I can call this method of the current view model when the application exits? I am able to do this:

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    // Do Something
    base.OnExit(e);
}
```

in the `App.Xaml.Mvx.cs` class that came with the MVVMCross Nuget package, and I believe that this is the right place to put the code I want to execute when the program exits.  The problem is that I do not have any reference to the current viewmodel.

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT/UPDATE:

I found a work around, it seems somewhat "hacky" but it gets the job done.  The class which holds the reference to the `SerialPort` I need to close is registered as a singleton within MVVMCross.  So, I added a field of the interface type of that singleton to the `App.Xaml.Mvx.cs` class, then at the end of `DoSetup()`, I call `Mvx.Resolve<>();` on that type and assign that result to the field I created.  Then, I have the `protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)`, where I can call the `Close()` and `Dispose()` methods on the field.  This does what I need it to do.

I am still interested if there is a better, "more correct" way to do it with MVVMCross, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you close an app the OnSuspending method is called and there I would write code for a *SerialPort* and because you want to fire a method of current *ViewModel* I would just have object representing current *ViewModel* in the App.xaml.cs so I can call method of it inside *OnSuspending()*

I would do it this way, but I don't know if it's better or can do what you need. But maybe it will give you an idea.